# Non-multiline left-aligned tabcontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, drawing

Is it possible to implement a scrollable, non-multiline, left-aligned tabcontrol in winforms?

If this is possible through owner-drawing, is there any existing code to use as a reference while implementing my own?

**EDIT:**
"Left-aligned" means the tabControl property is set: "Alignment=Left" (as opposed to Left-to-right).

Comment: No, the designer already refuses to let you do this.  You cannot use left-aligned tabs anyway, the visual style renderer has a bug in XP and Vista.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make your own in order to do that. You can have a look at [Y-et-A-nother TabControl](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12538/Y-et-A-nother-TabControl-A-Custom-Tab-Control-With) on how to do that.

Also, using WPF would probably be a lot easier to achieve that, but since you are using winform, you'll have to work a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

[How to: Display Side-Aligned Tabs with TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404305.aspx)